# Как сделать подобный эффект свечения у кнопки с помощью CSS?

Tags: css3

Есть кнопка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По поводу скругления и градиента вопросов нет.
Как с помощью CSS получить эффект белого свечения сверху?

Comment: Положить сверху элемент с нужным оазмером, opacity и белым box-shadow; возможно, есть вариант с радиальным градиентом. Проще в фотошопе сделать.

Comment: В фотошопе конечно проще, но хочется научиться делать на чистом CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так: http://jsfiddle.net/IonDen/ctsn0wu2/

```css
body {
    margin: 25px;
}

.button {
    position: relative;
    border: 0;
    padding: 25px 35px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    
    background: #ffbb00; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffbb00 0%, #998700 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ffbb00), color-stop(100%,#998700)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffbb00 0%,#998700 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #ffbb00 0%,#998700 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #ffbb00 0%,#998700 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffbb00 0%,#998700 100%);
}

.button:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    content: "";
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    border-radius: 50px;
    
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(top, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, top center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-radial-gradient(top, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* Opera 12+ */
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(top, ellipse cover,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at top,  rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%); /* W3C */
}
```

```html
<button class="button">Сделать звонок</button>
```

Для создания градиента можно использовать например этот инструмент: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: after'у наверняка всякие content и position надо прописать

Comment: Разумеется, в JSFIDDLE это все есть.

Comment: давайте это будет и здесь

Answer (score 3):

Помимо градиента для самой кнопки, нужно через дополнительный элемент (можно через `:after/:before` - без особой разницы) сделать белый [радиальный градиент](http://htmlbook.ru/css3-na-primerakh/radialnyi-gradient) с некой прозрачностью, поместив его координаты `в:вверху/ш:центре`, растянув его по ширине и половине высоты кнопки.

Пример:

```css
.button{
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  font-size: 1.9em;
  
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffd700, #b8860b);
}

.button span{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top center, rgba(255,255,255,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

```html
<div class='button'><span>I am button</span></div>
```